# Open eml file in any mail client and take screenshot

Tags: ruby, screenshot, email, eml

I perform a lot of tests that create e-mail messages. I store each message in separate eml file. (I can change file extension if needed.)

I would like to open each file in any mail client and take a screen shot, so I could visually inspect e-mails later.

The idea is that I could use a image viewing application to look at several screenshots in the same time, so I could visually compare them (after each test run).

I have access to Windows, Mac and Linux machines. I would prefer if the solution is in Ruby, but that is not required.

I am searching the web and this site, but no luck so far. I will post the solution in answer if I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you [can not automate Outlook Express](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177233). It accepts only `newsonly` and `mailonly` options when started from command line.

[Thunderbird accepts file name](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29) when started from command line:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" mail.eml
```

That was all I needed to open an e-mail in a mail client.

[snapit.exe](http://90kts.com/blog/2008/capturing-screenshots-in-watir/) takes the screen shot and saves it to file.

And here is the script to take the screen shot for multiple eml files.

```
file_names.each do |file_name|
  `start /d "#{thunderbird_folder}" thunderbird.exe #{file_name}`

  # if the script does not wait for a second, screen shot will be taken before
  # thunderbird opens
  sleep 1

  `snapit.exe`
end
```

Comment: The link to the snapit.exe-blog article is dead

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to take the screenshots

I never tried it, but there are ways to take screenshots and ways to use Ruby

From the [documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/ruby/classes/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#M000220) :

```
capture_screenshot(filename)

Captures a PNG screenshot to the specified file.

‘filename’ is the absolute path to the file to be written, e.g. "c:\blah\screenshot.png"
```

You can also take a look at [Page Glimpse](http://www.pageglimpse.com/) for these tasks.

The you need to find a way to automatize the "open email / take screenshot" procedure using this.